# Multidimensional array echo

Tags: php, arrays

```
 Array
(
[abc] => Array
    (
        [1] => 35
        [2] => 30
        [3] => 39
    )

[def] => Array
    (
        [1] => 30
        [2] => 32
        [3] => 29
    )

[ghi] => Array
    (
        [1] => 31
        [2] => 22
        [3] => 39
    )

)
```

I am trying to echo this multi dimensional array.

It works fine with print_r but I want to echo it and display the output as 
abc has 35 value in 1 and so on with every value.

```
foreach ($marks as $key => $val) {
  echo $val;
}
```

I know I have to pass every value indiviually but I dont know the syntax for it. Thanks
Please let me know how to correctly do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this using two for loop

```
  <?php

    foreach($marks as $key=>$value){

    echo $key;

    foreach($value as $key=>$marks){

    echo $key.'='.$marks.'<br>';
    }
    }
    ?>
```

**As per your question**

```
foreach($marks as $key=>$value){

echo $key.'&nbsp;has&nbsp<br>';


foreach($value as $key=>$marks){

echo $marks.'&nbsp;in&nbsp;'.$key.'<br>';

}
}
```

updated result

```
<?php

$marks=[
'mohammad'=>['physics'=>35,'maths'=>30,'chemistry'=>39],
'Qadir'=>['physics'=>30,'maths'=>32,'chemistry'=>29],
'zara'=>['physics'=>31,'maths'=>22,'chemistry'=>39]
];

foreach($marks as $key=>$value){

echo $key.'&nbsp;has&nbsp<br>';


foreach($value as $key=>$marks){

echo $marks.'&nbsp;in&nbsp;'.$key.'<br>';

}
echo "---------------------<br>";
}
?>
```

Output will be

```
mohammad has 
35 in physics
30 in maths
39 in chemistry
---------------------
Qadir has 
30 in physics
32 in maths
29 in chemistry
---------------------
zara has 
31 in physics
22 in maths
39 in chemistry
---------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this does what you wanted... feel free to modify appearance to your tastes :)

```
foreach ($marks as $key1 => $person) {
  foreach ($person as $subject => $val2) {
    echo ' '. $key1 .' has '. $person[$subject] .'marks in '. $subject .'<br>';
  }
}

//Array info:
//http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php
```

Comment: Oh okay, I had to write two loops for it. Thanks! this makes sense, Thank you!